# How to change the migration and not destroy anything?

Tags: postgresql

I have a user table and I should remove the NOT NULL restrictions from the firstname, username and lastname fields, do I understand correctly that nothing can be changed directly, do I need to add a new sql file and with the command? How can I remove NOT NULL and break nothing? everything breaks down

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (


 id                  SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
username            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
password            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
email               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
first_name          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_name           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_password_reset TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
roles               JSONB        NOT NULL,
active              BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
date_created        TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
date_updated        TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Comment: Why can't you just remove the `not null` from your script? Or do you want to change a table that was already created? Then use `alter table`

Comment: The table has already been created, but what will your example look like?

Comment: I found an example where all table restrictions are disabled, but I need to disable only some of them.

Comment: See the examples [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.8) (specifically the one titled "To remove a not-null constraint from a column")

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE user ALTER COLUMN username DROP NOT NULL;
```